# CSS inline-block vs float left: alignment mismatch

Tags: html, web, css

I am using a 980 grid, 8 margin, 2 padding and a width of 176 for each 'container', giving me 5 across.  I'm using Firefox to test things out.

I decided to test it out to make sure it worked, and originally had inline-block set for each grid size so that it would automatically line up. I was trying to put 5 across in a 980px wide container with 0 margin and 0 padding, but noticed that only 4 of the 176 size containers were lining up per 'row'.

I then changed from inline-block to float: left and suddenly, like magic, everything lines up properly and I can get 5 across within the container.  I checked it out, and inline-block is taking up an additional 4px per side per container somewhere (had to drop the width down to 172px with inline-block to get 5 containers to show up in one row).

My question: what is causing inline-block to use the additional 4px per side?  is this by design?  I'm not using borders or anything that would cause an increase in width.

Below is my CSS:

```
.gSite{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear:both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    background-color: blue;
}

.g1{
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 176px;
    float: left;

    background-color: red;
}

div#bodyContent{
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="bodyContent" class="gSite">
                    <div class="g1">
                        1A
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        2A
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        3A
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        4A
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        5A
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        1B
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        2B
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        3B
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        4B
                    </div>
                    <div class="g1">
                        5B
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / HTML% Mystery White space issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186388/css-html-mystery-white-space-issue)

Comment: Did you have any spaces between the `inline-blocks`?

Comment: @Rhumborl sligtly different, i know there's some weird problem (and how to fix it), but the linked question doesn't ask why it's doing it, just how to fix it.  I'd really like to use inline-block if possible cause it's much simpler and it should (to my knowledge) work the same

Comment: apparently putting the div on a new line counts as white space?  very odd.. is this a bug or is that intended to work like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are spaces between them - a line break and about 10 space characters. Compare this:

```css
.gSite {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear:both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
.g1 {
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 176px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
div#bodyContent {
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyContent" class="gSite">
    <div class="g1">1A</div>
    <div class="g1">2A</div>
    <div class="g1">3A</div>
    <div class="g1">4A</div>
    <div class="g1">5A</div>
    <div class="g1">1B</div>
    <div class="g1">2B</div>
    <div class="g1">3B</div>
    <div class="g1">4B</div>
    <div class="g1">5B</div>
</div>
```

**to this:**

```css
.gSite {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear:both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
.g1 {
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 176px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
div#bodyContent {
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyContent" class="gSite">
<div class="g1">1A</div><div class="g1">2A</div><div class="g1">3A</div><div class="g1">4A</div><div class="g1">5A</div><div class="g1">1B</div><div class="g1">2B</div><div class="g1">3B</div><div class="g1">4B</div><div class="g1">5B</div>
</div>
```

The only difference is removing the lines and space between the divs.

As the [link](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block#comment-61052) in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27186830/1901857) states:

> One problem that arrises[sic] when you use inline-block is that whitespace
>   in HTML becomes visual space on screen.

Why this is I have no idea - I suspect an archaic IE bug which needed to be persisted, as that is where `inline-block` first came from.

Comment: was basically jut typing this up as an answer, with http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block#comment-61052.  is a line break supposed to count as a space generally?  seems like it would be an easy thing for them to fix (then again I could be wrong) :-(  how do I keep anything readable and organized without the ability to use tabs and new lines?

Comment: You want a line break to work like a space for inline rendering. If it didn't when the browser rendered several lines of source text, the last word of one line would abut the first word of the next line and they would appear as all one word.

Comment: is there some sort of elegant solution using js by chance?  I'm not strong in js personally, don't know exactly how it would look.

Comment: @DavidTorrey - Counting JS as one solution, there are at least 15 solutions to the problem in its various guises, some in HTML, some in CSS, and the one in JS. None are elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the inheritance of the document's font size in the parent element. By specifying

```
font-size: 0;
```

on the parent, the clearance is removed.

In cases where you are scaling objects/elements by the root of the document. I'd recommend creating a helper class or similar, and attaching it to the body and elements in cases like this;

```
.null {
  font-size: 0;
}

.font-root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.333335%;
}
```

which could be used as such;

```
<body class="font-root">
    ...
    <div class="null"> /* removes all weird offsets for children */
      <div class="font-root column">Hi</div> /* restores base size for relative emulation */
      <div class="font-root column">Hi</div>
      <div class="font-root column">Hi</div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Would provide 3 equally divided columns. With good backwards compatibility also (not sure on how far).